# Can we publish a datasource on tableau server using tableau sdk?

Tags: sdk, tableau-api

I need to create a functionality where I can publish tableau extract on Server using Tableau SDK. Looking for some guidance.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

There is the underlying [Rest API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api.htm) (under which you would need to do a lot of programming including keeping track of sessions, variables, etc.  On top of these sit the [Server Client](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python) app or [Tableau_Tools](https://github.com/bryantbhowell/tableau_tools).

You can also publish through the command line/powershell with [tabcmd](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd_cmd.htm).